# opencart did not execute correct mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I add a new column in orders table (shopper_id) I am trying to get the data with the new column condition but result returns empty 
the query is correct and when I execute it directly it returns correct results

open cart formula

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added,o.shopper_id as shopper_id  , o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM  `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE  o.store_id = '" . (int) $store_id . "' AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int) $status . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND ( o.shopper_id = NULL OR o.shopper_id = '0' )  ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

Below is my mysql query-

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added,o.shopper_id, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM `medrahoc_order` o LEFT JOIN medrahoc_order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.store_id = '0' AND o.order_status_id = '1' AND os.language_id = '1' AND ( o.shopper_id = NULL OR o.shopper_id = 0 ) ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

my model function

```
public function getOrdersByStore($store_id, $status = null) {
            if (isset($status)) {
            $sql = "SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added,o.shopper_id as shopper_id  , o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM  `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE  o.store_id = '" . (int) $store_id . "' AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int) $status . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND o.shopper_id = '0'  ORDER BY o.order_id DESC";
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM  `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.store_id = '" . (int) $store_id . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND os.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.order_id DESC";
            }
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            return $query->rows;
        }
```

Comment: How do you conclude that there is no results from within Opencart (PHP)?

Comment: using this $this->db->query($sql);
and this is the result
{
    "success": 1,
    "error": [],
    "data": []
}

Comment: if i remove the o.shopper_id condition the result returns

Comment: You need to modify your WHERE condition to use shopper_id instead of o.shopper_id, I suppose.

Comment: @twicejr i did that its the same result

Comment: Maybe the same function is called multiple times, so the first time you check it might be correct that it has no results.

I'd try to set the global log on in mysql, to see the exact queries being executed and try to spot the difference or see the order / amount of queries being executed are happening different than expected. ` sudo mysql -uroot -proot --execute "SET GLOBAL general_log = 1";` (and then view / tail the general_log_file )

Comment: the function call is correct i tried many ways it work correctly

Comment: If the general_log shows exactly the same query as your own manual one, the culprit would be Opencart, otherwise it may be MySQL or another problem on the server.